# javascript string concatenation to jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know its a silly question to ask, but may be I am missing something.
So, I have

```
data = "ajey"
```

and then,

I want to select an `li` item from `ul` whose id is `"ajey"`

I am trying with

```
$('#users li#data').css('background-color', 'red');
```

but this returns an empty array. I know the mistake is in `li#data`

`#users` is the id of the ul element

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

since `ID`'s are unique, you can just to:

```
$('#' + data).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just concatenate the strings with `+` as you would normally do:

```
$('#users li#' + data).css('background-color', 'red');
```

If you are doing this, make sure that the value of `data` is trusted.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#users li#'+data).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$('#users li#' + data).css('background-color', 'red');
```